# Chrome extension resources not loading on file explorer or on an opened local pdf file. ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

I have a chrome extension written in manifest_version v3, The extension injects a react component which is encapsulated in shadow dom. The extension works fine on all web pages except when it comes to local file explorer (file://) which i try to open in a tab or if I open a pdf file that is stored on my machine in the browser, the resources are not loaded, I have mentioned the resources in the web_accessible_resources and set "<all_urls>" in the matches section, below is the error that I get and my "web_accessible_resources" element from manifest.json

```
GET chrome-extension://[ext_id]/styles/toolbox.css net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

"web_accessible_resources": [{
        "resources": ["content.styles.css", "icons/*", "styles/*"],
        "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*", "<all_urls>", "file://*"]
    }],
```

This is how I try to access the resources in my react app

```
chrome.runtime.getURL('/icons/icon-pen.png')
```

I have tried whatever is out there on StackOverflow but can't seem to figure out the issue, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's a bug in ManifestV3: https://crbug.com/1219825.

Comment: I read this I thought there still might be a solution but thanks @wOxxOm for letting me know